# error: psycopg2.OperationalError when trying to create a database in postgresql via sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am trying to create a database in postgresql via sqlalchemy.
when i try to run the following code:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker
import psycopg2

engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/postgres')
#connection = engine.connect()
base = declarative_base()

class schedule(base):
    __tablename__ = 'schedule'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    time = Column(String)
    monday = Column(String)
    tuesday = Column(String)
    wednesday = Column(String)
    thursday = Column(String)
    friday = Column(String)
    saturday = Column(String)

base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

I get an error: psycopg2.OperationalError

Traceback of error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2275, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 760, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 139, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 153, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 639, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 481, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 119, in <module>
    vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, run_as)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\debugger.py", line 39, in debug
    run()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "H:\prog_vs\chatBot\chatBot\chatBot\chatBot.py", line 23, in <module>
    base.metadata.create_all(engine)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 4304, in create_all
    ddl.SchemaGenerator, self, checkfirst=checkfirst, tables=tables
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2045, in _run_visitor
    with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2037, in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
    with self._contextual_connect() as conn:
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2239, in _contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2279, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1544, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2275, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 760, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 139, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 153, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 639, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 481, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError)
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The database looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRDQC.png)

Comment: Is the connection string `'postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/postgres'` the actual connection string, or a placeholder for this question? Looks like this comes down to not being able to connect.

Comment: this is what I actually use. I took this from :
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html
Paragraph: PostgreSQL
If more precisely line:
engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/mydatabase')
where I changed only "mydatabase" to the actual one.

Comment: In that case the odds are that your database does not have a user "scott" with the password "tiger".

Comment: Many thanks for the clear and polite answer(I understand that the question is stupid). The mistake is exactly what you said. In addition to this, I did not understand for a long time that there is a user for the database. I have previously tried to use a windows account user.

Comment: How can i close this question and select right answer?

Comment: These are comments, not proper answers yet. If an answer is written, follow these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. I'm not entirely sure, but I think you should be able to answer it yourself as well – and it's perfectly acceptable to do so – unless I've forgotten about some reputation limits that apply.

Comment: Ilja, you can totally put your comment as an answer so Fans can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

@ilja-everilä's comment answered this question:

> Is the connection string 'postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/postgres' the actual connection string, or a placeholder for this question? Looks like this comes down to not being able to connect.

The database connection URI was still using placeholder credentials (user "scott" with password "tiger") that weren't valid for the database.